# Installing nodejs/angular on Amazon ec2 instance

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

I have had nothing but problems with installing node and angular on my ec2 instance.  I have looked at a lot of help articles both on stack overflow and other places.  A lot of the articles on stack overflow include multiple comments that go like this:
Comment 1: "That worked for me!"
Comment 2: "Comment 1 is wrong, it did not work for me"

node/npm is constantly changing and there are so many flavors of Linux that I don't think one answer can possibly work for every instance.  I am a software guy, and while I can tinker with sys admin, I usually figure things out by using google...but that is not working here.  So let me explain what I have done and where I am in the process.

I have an Amazon ec2 server that has run for 18 months.  I had been able to install everything I want/need on it.  I started working on the MEAN stack about 9 months ago, and was following a book on how to install the stack.  I was able to get node, npm, mondo DB, and express installed and working.  I was able to connect to the application and everything worked.  I was able to install angular, but when I tried to create a project, I had nothing but problems.  I searched a lot of articles to try and fix things, but the further I went down the rabbit hole, the more things got messed up.

So I decided to spin up a fresh new ec2 AWS instance.  I used Redhat free tier.  I got everything up and running and was able to connect.  I then used yum to install mysql and an apache web server.  I had no issues getting that running.  I then decided to install node/npm/angular, and once again had no luck.

I started by trying to get node via yum, but I couldn't find a way to do that.  So I used the article that AWS gave for setting up node on ec2:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

That worked.  I had both node and npm.  So then I went about installing angular.  I found an article that suggested I do the following (logged in as the ec2-user)
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new

That caused my server to hang.  I needed to stop the instance and restart it before I could connect again.

Then I needed to start over with angular (from what I've read):
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g @angular/CLI
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

I confirmed that this worked when I typed npm -v

I then tried to create an angular app using:
ng new

This took a while and it looked like it hung my server.  I went to sleep and got up this morning and got the following:
Schematic workflow failed

### More researching.  I then ran a few checks.  When I ran ng --version, I get the following warning:

```
Node.js version v17.0.1 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. 
For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
            |___/
Angular CLI: 13.0.1
Node: 17.0.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: undefined
...
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1300.1
@angular-devkit/core         13.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.0.1
@angular/cli                 13.0.1
@schematics/angular          13.0.1
Warning: The current version of Node (17.0.1) is not supported by Angular.
```

---

I tried removing anything that had to do with angular and node after that.  I got rid of everything under my .nvm directory and similar files.

Finally, I tried following this article on Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/aenuk7/how_to_run_npm_install_and_ng_serve_on_ec2/

The above link is 3 years old, and I don't think these instructions are valid any more.

So I'd like to start over and get this working, and I need help since I don't understand the finer points.

Thanks

Comment: What distribution are you running?  (Including specific version?)

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Comment: ami-0ba62214afa52bec7

Comment: RHEL-8.4.0_HVM-20210504-x86_64-2-Hourly2-GP2